# Fail2ban on ubuntu igonres maxretry settings

Tags: security, ssh, brute-force, fail2ban

I have recently installed fail2ban on my Ubuntu server to protect ssh hack attempts. Everything is working as expected except the maxtetry as I set it to 3 times even though it banned the ip after 1st failed attempt. Below are the jail settings inside /etc/fail2ban/jail.local and when I check auth.log I see one attemp

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the fail2ban logs in :

> /var/log/fail2ban.log

Also, if you change the fail2ban config (jail.local) do a service restart :

> sudo /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart

Comment: Yes I do restart, and in the log it says 3

Comment: What do you mean it says 3 ? So in the logs appears that there were 3 failed login attempts and the ban ?

Comment: oooh sorry I mean it says 1 attempt not 3

Comment: ah, the name of ssh daemon is [sshd] not [ssh] . 

Probably you have the global maxretry = 1 and the [sshd] it's also enabled from /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/defaults-debian.conf

Comment: The issue solved after i set the maxretry to 5 times in the SSH and SSHD jail configuration.  Sounds weird but it worked :)

Comment: Worked because you've set the [SSHD] maxretry to 5, told you that there's no [SSH] daemon name